# How to fix "TypeError: Crud.Select_products is not a function”, error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to access an exported class from the Crud.js file, but I'm getting this error. My goal is to execute a sql query.

Error:

```
TypeError: Crud.Select_products is not a function
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\server.js:7:24
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
  at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
  at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
  at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
  at expressInit (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\react\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I'm using NodeJs in version 10.15.0, I already tried changing the way to export, but I still have the same error.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var Crud = require('./database/Crud');
var app = express();


app.get('/api/home', function(req, res){
    let results = Crud.Select_products();
    res.send(results);

});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Escutando na porta 5000'));
```

Crud.js

```
var Connect = require('./Connect');

Class Crud {

  constructor(){
    Connect.Connecting();
  }

  Select_products(where){
    if(where !== undefined){
        let sql = 'Select * from produtos where id_produto = ?';
        Connect.query(sql, [where], function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            return result;
        });
    }else{
        Connect.query('Select * from produtos', function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            return result;
        });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Crud;
```

I expect to receive the data from database.

Comment: I don't know what connect does, but I cannot see how `Select_products` would be an element of Crud right now. You have to put it into the class, right now it is just a local function in the Crud file

Comment: The file Connect just connect to database.

Comment: Select_products is inside the class, it's just not formatted correctly - looks like it lost some tabs when it was pasted in, but that should work fine.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that, you are right @Joseph. Did you try to instanciate Crud? meaning using `new Crud()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crud is a class, and you are trying to access a method, methods belongs to instances.

You can either export a instance, creating a singleton pattern like:

```
module.exports = new Crud();
```

Or you can create an instance at your `server.js`, and call the method

```
var Crud = require('./database/Crud');
var crud = new Crud();

app.get('/api/home', function(req, res){
  let results = crud.Select_products();
  res.send(results);
});
```

Also, when you get this to work, you will realize you have more problems. Your `Select_products()` function doesn't return anything. You might want to send a callback function to it, or use `async/await` and promises, if the library you are using supports promises